# How to pass a multiword string as argument in Linux

Tags: bash, variable, string, function

I am trying to pass a multiword argument in a function an echo the result in a simple fashion.

Currently I am doing this:

```
function myFunction { 
    multiWordString=""  
    for ((i=3; i<=$#; i++)); do 
            multiwordVariable+=" "${!i} 
    done 
    echo "multiwordVariable here => $multiwordSTRING"  
}

myFunction "$@" otherArgument1 otherArgument2 I am a multivariable element and yeah is rock
```

You can see there is several drawback in this approach, the insertion of multiple argument, the usage of a loop, the management of my argument positioning to retrieve my string of characters... that makes it a very approximating solution.

I would do something more simple, like just read my variable's string:

```
multiWordArgument="here an awesome multiword string"

function file_function { 
    echo $1 
}
myFunction $multiWordArgument
```

maybe someone know a way that is nearer to this process?

thanks

Comment: I'm confused by this.  Can you not just quote the entire argument?

Comment: indeed.  e.g. `myFunction "$multiWordArgument"`

Comment: @Jesse_b thanks, it works :).

Comment: @Jesse_b thanks for the link :), seems very interesting

Comment: @Webwoman: When using bash/sh it is more than interesting, it is doctrine.  As is: [Security implications of forgetting to quote a variable in bash/POSIX shells](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/171346/237982)

Answer (score 0):

What is wrong with?:

```
function myFunction {     echo "$@";    }

myFunction "$@" Arg1 Arg2 I am a multivariable element and yeah is rock
```

Running that script will print:

```
$ ./script Hello World!

Hello World! Arg1 Arg2 I am a multivariable element and yeah is rock
```

Or, if you want to convert all the arguments to an string (separated by spaces):

```
IFS=$' \t\n' var=$*
```

Or, in some shells: `var="$@"` (not setting IFS).